# RDO install OpenStack queens all-in-one get stuck

Tags: openstack, rdo

When I use packstack to install openstack queens allinone, it got stuck at:

```
# sudo packstack --answer-file pack-1534411186.txt
Welcome to the Packstack setup utility

The installation log file is available at: /var/tmp/packstack/20180816-022431-Qun9eG/openstack-setup.log

Installing:
Clean Up                                             [ DONE ]
Discovering ip protocol version                      [ DONE ]
Setting up ssh keys                                  [ DONE ]
...

Testing if puppet apply is finished: 10.145.xxx.yyy_controller.pp  [ | ]
```

I find the log mention above, the last line seems no help:

```
tar --dereference -cpzf - aodh apache ceilometer certmonger cinder concat firewall glance gnocchi heat horizon inifile ironic keystone magnum manila memcached mysql neutron nova nssdb openstack openstacklib oslo ovn packstack panko rabbitmq redis remote rsync sahara ssh stdlib swift sysctl tempest trove vcsrepo vswitch xinetd | ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null root@10.145.115.45 tar -C /var/tmp/packstack/a73923ae3b8f4332b9fa71e5f30902f0/modules -xpzf -
```

Also I go to the puppet running file and find some warning there:

```
# ps -ef | grep puppet
root      1870  1869  0 02:25 ?        00:00:00 flock /var/tmp/packstack/a73923ae3b8f4332b9fa71e5f30902f0/ps.lock puppet apply --modulepath /var/tmp/packstack/a73923ae3b8f4332b9fa71e5f30902f0/modules /var/tmp/packstack/a73923ae3b8f4332b9fa71e5f30902f0/manifests/10.145.115.45_controller.pp
...


Warning: ModuleLoader: module 'mysql' has unresolved dependencies - it will only see those that are resolved. Use 'puppet module list --tree' to see information about modules
   (file & line not available)
Warning: ModuleLoader: module 'keystone' has unresolved dependencies - it will only see those that are resolved. Use 'puppet module list --tree' to see information about modules
   (file & line not available)
Warning: This method is deprecated, please use the stdlib validate_legacy function,
                    with Stdlib::Compat::String. There is further documentation for validate_legacy function in the README. at ["/var/tmp/packstack/a73923ae3b8f4332b9fa71e5f30902f0/modules/keystone/manifests/db/mysql.pp", 63]:["/var/tmp/packstack/a73923ae3b8f4332b9fa71e5f30902f0/manifests/10.145.115.45_controller.pp", 21]
   (at /var/tmp/packstack/a73923ae3b8f4332b9fa71e5f30902f0/modules/stdlib/lib/puppet/functions/deprecation.rb:28:in `deprecation')
Warning: ModuleLoader: module 'cinder' has unresolved dependencies - it will only see those that are resolved. Use 'puppet module list --tree' to see information about modules
   (file & line not available)
Warning: ModuleLoader: module 'glance' has unresolved dependencies - it will only see those that are resolved. Use 'puppet module list --tree' to see information about modules
   (file & line not available)
Warning: ModuleLoader: module 'gnocchi' has unresolved dependencies - it will only see those that are resolved. Use 'puppet module list --tree' to see information about modules
   (file & line not available)
Warning: ModuleLoader: module 'aodh' has unresolved dependencies - it will only see those that are resolved. Use 'puppet module list --tree' to see information about modules
   (file & line not available)
Warning: ModuleLoader: module 'neutron' has unresolved dependencies - it will only see those that are resolved. Use 'puppet module list --tree' to see information about modules
   (file & line not available)
Warning: ModuleLoader: module 'nova' has unresolved dependencies - it will only see those that are resolved. Use 'puppet module list --tree' to see information about modules
   (file & line not available)
Warning: Unknown variable: '::nova::db::mysql_api::setup_cell0'. at /var/tmp/packstack/a73923ae3b8f4332b9fa71e5f30902f0/modules/nova/manifests/db/mysql.pp:53:28
Warning: ModuleLoader: module 'openstacklib' has unresolved dependencies - it will only see those that are resolved. Use 'puppet module list --tree' to see information about modules
   (file & line not available)
Warning: This method is deprecated, please use the stdlib validate_legacy function,
                    with Stdlib::Compat::Hash. There is further documentation for validate_legacy function in the README. at ["/var/tmp/packstack/a73923ae3b8f4332b9fa71e5f30902f0/modules/keystone/manifests/policy.pp", 34]:["/var/tmp/packstack/a73923ae3b8f4332b9fa71e5f30902f0/modules/keystone/manifests/init.pp", 787]
   (at /var/tmp/packstack/a73923ae3b8f4332b9fa71e5f30902f0/modules/stdlib/lib/puppet/functions/deprecation.rb:28:in `deprecation')
Warning: This method is deprecated, please use the stdlib validate_legacy function,
                    with Pattern[]. There is further documentation for validate_legacy function in the README. at ["/var/tmp/packstack/a73923ae3b8f4332b9fa71e5f30902f0/modules/keystone/manifests/init.pp", 806]:["/var/tmp/packstack/a73923ae3b8f4332b9fa71e5f30902f0/manifests/10.145.115.45_controller.pp", 27]
   (at /var/tmp/packstack/a73923ae3b8f4332b9fa71e5f30902f0/modules/stdlib/lib/puppet/functions/deprecation.rb:28:in `deprecation')
Warning: Scope(Class[Cinder::Keystone::Authtoken]): revocation_cache_time parameter is deprecated, has no effect and will be removed in the future.
Warning: This method is deprecated, please use the stdlib validate_legacy function,
                    with Stdlib::Compat::Bool. There is further documentation for validate_legacy function in the README. at ["/var/tmp/packstack/a73923ae3b8f4332b9fa71e5f30902f0/modules/cinder/manifests/api.pp", 220]:["/var/tmp/packstack/a73923ae3b8f4332b9fa71e5f30902f0/manifests/10.145.115.45_controller.pp", 45]
   (at /var/tmp/packstack/a73923ae3b8f4332b9fa71e5f30902f0/modules/stdlib/lib/puppet/functions/deprecation.rb:28:in `deprecation')
Warning: Scope(Class[Nova::Db]): placement_database_connection has no effect as of pike, and may be removed in a future release
Warning: Scope(Class[Nova::Db]): placement_slave_connection has no effect as of pike, and may be removed in a future release
Warning: This method is deprecated, please use the stdlib validate_legacy function,
                    with Stdlib::Compat::Array. There is further documentation for validate_legacy function in the README. at ["/var/tmp/packstack/a73923ae3b8f4332b9fa71e5f30902f0/modules/nova/manifests/init.pp", 564]:["/var/tmp/packstack/a73923ae3b8f4332b9fa71e5f30902f0/manifests/10.145.115.45_controller.pp", 74]
   (at /var/tmp/packstack/a73923ae3b8f4332b9fa71e5f30902f0/modules/stdlib/lib/puppet/functions/deprecation.rb:28:in `deprecation')
Warning: Scope(Class[Nova::Api]): The default_floating_pool parameter is deprecated. Please use nova::network::neutron::default_floating_pool instead.
Warning: Scope(Class[Nova::Api]): The pci_alias parameter is deprecated. Please use nova::pci::aliases instead.
Warning: Unknown variable: 'until_complete_real'. at /var/tmp/packstack/a73923ae3b8f4332b9fa71e5f30902f0/modules/nova/manifests/cron/archive_deleted_rows.pp:77:82
Warning: This method is deprecated, please use match expressions with Stdlib::Compat::Array instead. They are described at https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/latest/reference/lang_data_type.html#match-expressions. at ["/var/tmp/packstack/a73923ae3b8f4332b9fa71e5f30902f0/modules/nova/manifests/scheduler/filter.pp", 140]:["/var/tmp/packstack/a73923ae3b8f4332b9fa71e5f30902f0/manifests/10.145.115.45_controller.pp", 80]
   (at /var/tmp/packstack/a73923ae3b8f4332b9fa71e5f30902f0/modules/stdlib/lib/puppet/functions/deprecation.rb:28:in `deprecation')
Warning: This method is deprecated, please use match expressions with Stdlib::Compat::Ip_address instead. They are described at https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/latest/reference/lang_data_type.html#match-expressions. at ["/var/tmp/packstack/a73923ae3b8f4332b9fa71e5f30902f0/modules/nova/manifests/compute/neutron.pp", 31]:["/var/tmp/packstack/a73923ae3b8f4332b9fa71e5f30902f0/manifests/10.145.115.45_controller.pp", 85]
   (at /var/tmp/packstack/a73923ae3b8f4332b9fa71e5f30902f0/modules/stdlib/lib/puppet/functions/deprecation.rb:28:in `deprecation')
Warning: Scope(Class[Neutron::Plugins::Ml2]): supported_pci_vendor_devs is deprecated, has no effect and will be removed in a future release.
Warning: ModuleLoader: module 'horizon' has unresolved dependencies - it will only see those that are resolved. Use 'puppet module list --tree' to see information about modules
   (file & line not available)
Warning: This method is deprecated, please use the stdlib validate_legacy function,
                    with Stdlib::Compat::Absolute_Path. There is further documentation for validate_legacy function in the README. at ["/var/tmp/packstack/a73923ae3b8f4332b9fa71e5f30902f0/modules/horizon/manifests/init.pp", 610]:["/var/tmp/packstack/a73923ae3b8f4332b9fa71e5f30902f0/manifests/10.145.115.45_controller.pp", 123]
   (at /var/tmp/packstack/a73923ae3b8f4332b9fa71e5f30902f0/modules/stdlib/lib/puppet/functions/deprecation.rb:28:in `deprecation')
Warning: ModuleLoader: module 'swift' has unresolved dependencies - it will only see those that are resolved. Use 'puppet module list --tree' to see information about modules
   (file & line not available)
Warning: Unknown variable: 'methods_real'. at /var/tmp/packstack/a73923ae3b8f4332b9fa71e5f30902f0/modules/swift/manifests/proxy/tempurl.pp:100:56
Warning: Unknown variable: 'incoming_remove_headers_real'. at /var/tmp/packstack/a73923ae3b8f4332b9fa71e5f30902f0/modules/swift/manifests/proxy/tempurl.pp:101:56
Warning: Unknown variable: 'incoming_allow_headers_real'. at /var/tmp/packstack/a73923ae3b8f4332b9fa71e5f30902f0/modules/swift/manifests/proxy/tempurl.pp:102:56
Warning: Unknown variable: 'outgoing_remove_headers_real'. at /var/tmp/packstack/a73923ae3b8f4332b9fa71e5f30902f0/modules/swift/manifests/proxy/tempurl.pp:103:56
Warning: Unknown variable: 'outgoing_allow_headers_real'. at /var/tmp/packstack/a73923ae3b8f4332b9fa71e5f30902f0/modules/swift/manifests/proxy/tempurl.pp:104:56
Warning: Scope(Class[Swift::Storage::All]): The default port for the object storage server has changed from 6000 to 6200 and will be changed in a later release
Warning: Scope(Class[Swift::Storage::All]): The default port for the container storage server has changed from 6001 to 6201 and will be changed in a later release
Warning: Scope(Class[Swift::Storage::All]): The default port for the account storage server has changed from 6002 to 6202 and will be changed in a later release
Warning: Scope(Class[Gnocchi::Logging]): gnocchi::logging::logging_context_format_string is deprecated and will be removed in future
Warning: Scope(Class[Gnocchi::Logging]): gnocchi::logging::logging_default_format_string is deprecated and will be removed in future
Warning: Scope(Class[Gnocchi::Logging]): gnocchi::logging::logging_debug_format_suffix is deprecated and will be removed in future
Warning: Scope(Class[Gnocchi::Logging]): gnocchi::logging::logging_exception_prefix is deprecated and will be removed in future
Warning: Scope(Class[Gnocchi::Logging]): gnocchi::logging::log_config_append is deprecated and will be removed in future
Warning: Scope(Class[Gnocchi::Logging]): gnocchi::logging::default_log_levels is deprecated and will be removed in future
Warning: Scope(Class[Gnocchi::Logging]): gnocchi::logging::publish_errors is deprecated and will be removed in future
Warning: Scope(Class[Gnocchi::Logging]): gnocchi::logging::fatal_deprecations is deprecated and will be removed in future
Warning: Scope(Class[Gnocchi::Logging]): gnocchi::logging::instance_format is deprecated and will be removed in future
Warning: Scope(Class[Gnocchi::Logging]): gnocchi::logging::instance_uuid_format is deprecated and will be removed in future
Warning: Scope(Class[Gnocchi::Logging]): gnocchi::logging::log_date_format is deprecated and will be removed in future
Warning: Scope(Class[Gnocchi::Api]): host is deprecated
Warning: Scope(Class[Gnocchi::Statsd]): user_id parameter is deprecated and will be removed in the future release.
Warning: Scope(Class[Gnocchi::Statsd]): project_id parameter is deprecated and will be removed in the future release.
Warning: ModuleLoader: module 'ceilometer' has unresolved dependencies - it will only see those that are resolved. Use 'puppet module list --tree' to see information about modules
   (file & line not available)
Warning: Scope(Class[Ceilometer::Agent::Central]): This class is deprecated. Please use ceilometer::agent::central with central namespace instead.
Warning: ModuleLoader: module 'redis' has unresolved dependencies - it will only see those that are resolved. Use 'puppet module list --tree' to see information about modules
   (file & line not available)
Warning: ModuleLoader: module 'rabbitmq' has unresolved dependencies - it will only see those that are resolved. Use 'puppet module list --tree' to see information about modules
   (file & line not available)
Warning: ModuleLoader: module 'oslo' has unresolved dependencies - it will only see those that are resolved. Use 'puppet module list --tree' to see information about modules
   (file & line not available)
```

What's the problem? My basic setup steps and environment are as following:

CentOS-7-x86_64-Minimal-1611: 8 cores and 16GB mem.

```
sudo yum update -y
sudo yum install -y centos-release-openstack-queens
yum update -y && yum install -y openstack-packstack
cat << EOF > /etc/environment
LANG=en_US.utf-8
LC_ALL=en_US.utf-8
EOF
packstack --gen-answer-file pack-`date +%s`.txt
<configure as following>
CONFIG_KEYSTONE_ADMIN_PW=default
CONFIG_CONTROLLER_HOST=10.145.xxx.yyy
CONFIG_COMPUTE_HOSTS=10.145.xxx.yyy
CONFIG_NETWORK_HOSTS=10.145.xxx.yyy
CONFIG_LBAAS_INSTALL=y

sudo systemctl disable firewalld
sudo systemctl stop firewalld
sudo systemctl disable NetworkManager
sudo systemctl stop NetworkManager
sudo systemctl enable network
sudo systemctl start network

uname -m | grep -q 'x86_64'  && echo 'centos' >/etc/yum/vars/contentdir || echo 'altarch' >/etc/yum/vars/contentdir

packstack --answer-file <answer file>
```